# Django + MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Im trying to use MongoDB together with Django.
I've followed this guide to set it up so all necessary things is installed.
[MongoDB + Django tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/)
My problem is as follows:
When trying to run `cities = City.objects.get()` in my `views.py` I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /GetAllCities/
        City matching query does not exist.
```

My MongoDB looks like this

```
Databasename = "exjobb"
Collectioname = "cities"`
```

And it contains 30,000 rows of data, it works with my Rails and PHP application.

My model class looks like this

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField

    # Create your models here.
    class City(models.Model):
        city = models.TextField()
        loc = models.TextField()
        population = models.IntegerField()
        state = models.TextField()
        _id = models.IntegerField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.city
```

And one row in the database looks like this

```
{
     "city" : "ACMAR",
     "loc" : [
        -86.51557,
        33.584132
     ],
     "population" : 6055,
     "state" : "AL",
     "_id" : "35004"
}
```

Comment: Your question reads: " trying to use MongoDB together with Django", So why do you wish to chose a **new ORM** like django-mongodb-engine? Why not connect the **existing** Django ORM to MongoDB using a [connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/) like djongo?

Comment: Djongo did not exist when I asked the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was that I didn't know how to choose which collection to use. So Django created a new collection named "myAppName_cities".

To tell django which collection to use, just add a meta class like this.

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.TextField()
    loc = models.TextField()
    population = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.TextField()
        #Specify collection in the MongoMetaclass
    class MongoMeta:
        db_table = "cities"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the cities in your DB you should use

```
cities = City.objects.all()
```

`City.objects.get` needs a keyword argument to search on and only returns a single record. Raising an exception if it finds more than one.

Comment: I switched to .all, now I dont get any errors but my cities is empty. len(cities) = 0, but it should be 30 000...I've had a similiar problem with rails, I had to rename my Rails City model to "cities"...

Comment: Are you calling it properly? From looking at your code on github I see this line in your `get_all_cities` function: `cities = City.objects.all`. It should be `cities = City.objects.all()`. You're missing the brackets so are just assigning the function to cities...

Comment: Well your code looks correct. How are you putting the data into MongoDB? What happens if you open up a manage.py shell and use that to create a city. Can you then retrieve it?

Comment: I've used this script to create the database
        mongoimport --db exjobb --collection cities --file zips.json
When using manage.py shell and trying to get City.objects.all() I get "City is not defined"

Comment: You need to import the `City` class before you use it. Something like `from  exjobbApp.exjobbApplication.models import City`. Once you have imported City you can create a city record with `City.objects.create(city="Paris", loc="France")`. Then City.objects.all() should return something. If that is the case it means you are not adding the data correctly in your script.

Comment: Hmmm some progress, perhaps? When trying to save the object I get this:
`city=City.objects.create(city = "Skara", loc = "France", population = 54364, state = "AL", _id = "63464344")`

Then I run `city.save()`

`InvalidId: AutoField (default primary key) values must be strings representing an ObjectId on MongoDB (got u'63464344' instead)`

So the connnection to the DB seems to work atleast?

Comment: And what happens why you try that command without providing the `_id`?   You might want to strip `_id` out of your model anyway. It seems like that is an autofield that is created by default.

Comment: It works when adding data from the shell. City.objects.all() returns what I just entered, but not all of the other data that's in the database? Somehow I think the connection to the database is Wrong, it should show 30000+ rows...

Comment: Okey the problem is the following: When inserting data to the MongoDB from django, I noticed that it  created a new Collection, "exjobbApp_city" and it did not use the collection cities. How can I tell django to use the cities collection? I've imported a new collection and named it exjobbApp_city and then my code works and returns 30000 rows! But that's not a good solution, I want to tell Django which collection to use.

Comment: It's a fine solution. That's how Django's ORM (Object Relationship Manager) works. You don't have to use it but I would suggest you do.